# Domain class auto validation in grails

Tags: grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am fetching list of results from database but the list doesn't validates the constraints until i call "validate()" method for each objects.

```
    def temp = ConfigInfo.where { projectId == project }.findAll()

    //at this stage domain class is not validated
    temp.each {         
        println "validate" + it.validate()
        println "has error" +  it.hasErrors()
    } 
          //in the above code block validate() is called, I don't want to do this.
```

// is it possible to configure it happen automatically and i get the validated objects.

I don't want to invoke validate method. 
is there any way or configuration in grails such that domain class get validated automatically.

Please help me in this.

Comment: If you are getting your data from the table and not changing values why do you need to validate it again?

Answer (score 0):

Grails domain class objects get validated before save.

Use the following in your domain model to set the validation rules:

```
static constraints = {
   // whatever you want to validate
}
```

Whenever you save an object it will be validated by the constraints you set. When the object is persistent in the database it has always been validated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is that just define all your validation in constraints closure.
e.g.

```
    static constraints = {
                id maxLength: 5
                //etc...
}
```

at the time of saving object you just need to check object is validate or not!, it will return true/false.
look this:  [click here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Constraints/Usage.html)